# Append Signature When Invoking Mutt via Command Line

Tags: signature, mutt

I looked everywhere, but could not find an answer. When I invoke mutt via a script or via a simple cmd line entry (see below), the signature never gets appended. Is it possible to do this? When I compose an email via the mutt gui it works fine. :{

echo "TEST" | mutt -s "TEST SIG 1" user@example.com

Comment: As it is said here: http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#signature, you need a file named '.signature' in your home directory, containing the signature.

Comment: I have that and it works fine when composing a message via the UI. It's only via a script or via the cmd line that the signature is not appended.

Comment: Attention `-s` is not for specifying the signature. It is used for the message subject.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack.

```
mutt -s "message subject" user@example.com < /path/to/message < /path/to/signature
```

Comment: That may work. My problem is that currently I typically save the message as a variable, so my usual command is like below. When I try to direct the signature it looks like it just overwrites the intended message body.

echo -e "$Message_txt" | mutt -s "TEST SIG" user@example.com < /path/to/signature

The body is only the signature. I think if I rewrote my scripts to save the message body txt as a file vs just saving it as a variable I could get it to work. 

The below returns an ambiguous redirect. :(

mutt -s "TEST SIG" user@example.com < $Message_txt < /path/to/signature

Comment: `echo $Message_txt > /tmp/m.txt && mutt -s "message subject" user@example.com < /tmp/m.txt < /path/to/signature && rm -f /tmp/m.txt` or `echo "message body" > /tmp/m.txt && mutt -s "message subject" user@example.com < /tmp/m.txt < /path/to/signature && rm -f /tmp/m.txt`